# Add entries from one table to an existing one (Both tables have entries already)

Tags: mysql

I want to add entries/rows from one table (y) to another (X) (match them): The columns (and the name of the columns) in both are completely equal. How Can I do this?
(Both tables have entries already.)

I tried it like:

```
INSERT INTO X(OrderID, OrderDate, Payment, ArticleID, Price) 
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Payment, ArticleID, Price 
FROM Y;
```

-> But I got this error = Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Do you have other columns in X / Y table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you missed  the space between  table name and list of column

```
INSERT INTO X ( OrderID, OrderDate, Payment, ArticleID, Price) 
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Payment, ArticleID, Price 
FROM Y;
```

Comment: No that´s not the problem in my querry

Comment: the formal sintax of the  query is correct  be sure : 1 ) this is the exact query you are using, 2 ) the column have the same corresponding type .. eventually udpate your question adding the related  table schema  ..